# JSON Library that working against interfaces

Tags: java, json

Does anyone know a Java JSON parser that works against Java interfaces and generates the implementation (at runtime). Analogous to the way Databinding in [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding) works, but for the server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson's [MrBean](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureMaterializedBeans) extension is the only one I've used. Simply register the MrBean module with your ObjectMapper and any interfaces or abstract classes Jackson encounters will be materialized by MrBean automatically (any annotation on the interface or abstract class would take precedence if you want to create exceptions to this).

EDIT: [Article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_459.html) with more detail

Answer (score 1):

GWT AutoBeans are one option.  They can be used on both the client and the server.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean

Answer (score 0):

Google GSON maybe is another option. It supports custom serialization and deserialization, so you can do anything what you want:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/